# Soap-UI 5.2.1 is giving UnknownHostException for an private URL but is working for another person

Tags: testing, soapui, unknown-host

I got the Soap Ui project from a colleague. The same project is used by that colleague and is working fine.

I have already tried setting the vmoptions file for Soap-UI. But, it is not working.

Is there a specific reason that this might occur?

EDIT:
As per Tim's suggestion adding some more details -
I have already been using Soap UI for sometime and other test cases are running fine.
Had setup vmoptions config early on.
I can hit other other domains on the same network.
I'm using MacOS and aforementioned colleague is using Windows. He sent me the xml project and I imported it.

Comment: First thing to check is can you hit this private URL from somewhere else, e.g. a web browser (or ping from the command line)?  If not, then this isn't a SOAP UI problem.

Comment: I can hit it through  other channels. For example, the Soap Ui "Test on Demand" is hitting it, too. Not sure why the TestSteps are failing. Don't really want to use Test on Demand everytime

Comment: I thought maybe there's some settings or any setup that I'm missing.

Comment: I can't guess where the problem is, but you may want to include your config steps in case you missed something and a SOAP UI expert can help here.

Comment: Yeah, let's see. Thanks.